# lookup enum using a range in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum AccountRange {

    RANGE1("100,200"), RANGE2("201,300"), RANGE3("301,900");


    private final String rangeAccount;

    private static final Map<String, AccountRange> lookup = new HashMap<String, AccountRange>();

    static {
        for (AccountRange d : AccountRange.values()) {
            lookup.put(d.getRangeAccount(), d);
        }
    }

    private AccountRange(String rangeAccount) {
        this.rangeAccount = rangeAccount;
    }

    public String getRangeAccount() {
        return rangeAccount;
    }

    public static AccountRange get(String abbreviation) {
        return lookup.get(abbreviation);
    }

}
```

To return `RANGE1` i need call the enum using: `AccountRange.get("100,200")`

But the problem is that I need to call the enum with a simple value for example:

`AccountRange.get("108")` and I need that the enum returns `RANGE1` because 108  is in the first range between 100 and 200

`AccountRange.get("600")` and I need that the enum returns`RANGE3`

Comment: Does it need to be stringly typed like you did? Can't you use a numeric types instead?

Comment: Yes, all ranges are numeric

Comment: But I don't can use a ENUM for each number, because are large ranges. I think with a String, but other better solution is great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the range as a pair of integers, and iterate over the enum's values in order to find a range that contains the argument you're looking for:

```
public enum AccountRange {

    RANGE1(100, 200), RANGE2(201, 300), RANGE3(301, 900);

    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    private AccountRange(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public String getRangeAccount() {
        return String.format("%d,%d", min, max);
    }

    public static AccountRange get(int val) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                     .filter(r -> val >= r.min && val <= r.max)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the format is not applicable for arguments (int,int) Or the IDE tell me that

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle I don't understand this sentence. Can you clarify?

Comment: return "%d,%d".format(min, max);  -> The method format(String,Object)  s not applicable for arguments (int,int)

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle sorry about that, forgot Java's `String#format` is static. Edited and fixed my answer.

Comment: .findFirst(r -> val >= r.min && val <= r.max) won't work. As it does not take any argument.

Comment: Yes findFirst does not take any argument

Comment: @GauravSrivastav damn, my Java is rusty. You should filter with that expression and then call `findFirst`. I've edited my answer accordingly - thanks for noticing!

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle damn, my Java is rusty. You should filter with that expression and then call `findFirst`. I've edited my answer accordingly - thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in an alternative solution with [google.common.collect](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) :

```
    RangeMap<Integer, String> rangeMap = TreeRangeMap.create();
    rangeMap.put(Range.closed(100, 200), "RANGE1");
    rangeMap.put(Range.closed(201, 300), "RANGE2");
    rangeMap.put(Range.closed(301, 900), "RANGE3");

    System.out.println(rangeMap.get(108));//RAGE1
    System.out.println(rangeMap.get(600));//RAGE3
```

Comment: Interesting proposition!

Comment: Thanks for yout poposition, is very very interesting!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you could do if you wanna stick to enums:

```
public enum AccountRange {

    RANGE1 (100, 200), 
    RANGE2 (201, 300), 
    RANGE3 (301, 900);

    private final long min;
    private final long max;

    private AccountRange (long min, long max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public long getRangeMin () {
        return min;
    }

    public long getRangeMax () {
        return min;
    }

    public static AccountRange get (long value) {
        AccountRange[] accRanges = values ();

        for (AccountRange accRange : accRanges) {
            long minRange = accRange.getRangeMin ();
            long maxRange = accRange.getRangeMax ();

            if (value >= minRange && value <= maxRange) {
                return accRange;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Down-vote for using array to store two individual values of different meaning.

Comment: You're right, using a Tuple (even though not native in Java) would have made more sense, or simply 2 long variables.

Comment: Yes, two variables. Using varargs, when you want exactly 2 arguments, is wrong, since compiler won't enforce argument count. Using array to store two values, when two fields will do, is wrong, especially when the values have different meaning (min vs max). Naming them will clarify the meaning.

Comment: Updated for future visitors.